# HTML-теги в php

Tags: php, html

Столкнулся с интересной проблемой, решить которую самостоятельно не удаётся. В общем, суть в том, что функция вида :

```
<div>
        <ul id="block-product-grid">
            <?php
                if(!empty($cat) && !empty($type)){
                    $querycat = "AND brand='$cat' AND type_product='$type'";
                } else {
                    if(!empty($type)){
                        $querycat = "AND type_product='$type'";
                    } else {
                        $querycat= "";
                    }
                }
                $result =  mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM  `table_products` WHERE visible='1' $querycat ORDER BY $sorting");
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                    do {
                        if ($row["image"] != "" && file_exists("./uploads_images/".$row["image"])) {
                            $img_path = './uploads_images/'.$row["image"];
                            $max_width = 200;
                            $max_height = 200;
                            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img_path);
                            $ratioh = $max_height/$height;
                            $ratiow = $max_width/$width;
                            $ratio = min($ratioh, $ratiow);
                            $width = intval($ratio*$width);
                            $height = intval($ratio*$height);
                        } else {
                            $img_path = "/images/no-image.png";
                            $width = 110;
                            $height = 200;
                        }

                        echo('
                            <li>
                                <div class="block-images-grid"><img src="'.$img_path.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" alt="img"></div>
                                <p class="style-title-grid">
                                    <a href="#">'.$row["title"].'</a>
                                </p>
                                <ul class="reviews-and-counts">
                                    <li><img src="/images/eye-icon.png" alt="eye"><p>0</p></li>
                                    <li><img src="/images/comment-icon.png" alt="comment"><p>0</p></li>
                                </ul>
                                <a href="#" class="add-cart-style-grid"></a>
                                <p class="style-price-grid">
                                    <strong>'.$row["price"].'</strong> грн
                                </p>
                                <div class="mini-features">
                                    '.$row["mini_features"].'
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        ');
                    } while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
             ?>
        </ul>
        <ul id="block-product-list">
            <?php
                $result =  mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM  `table_products` WHERE visible='1' $querycat ORDER BY $sorting");
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                    do {
                        if ($row["image"] != "" && file_exists("./uploads_images/".$row["image"])) {
                            $img_path = './uploads_images/'.$row["image"];
                            $max_width = 150;
                            $max_height = 150;
                            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img_path);
                            $ratioh = $max_height/$height;
                            $ratiow = $max_width/$width;
                            $ratio = min($ratioh, $ratiow);
                            $width = intval($ratio*$width);
                            $height = intval($ratio*$height);
                        } else {
                            $img_path = "/images/noimages80x70.png";
                            $width = 80;
                            $height = 70;
                        }

                        echo('
                            <li>
                                <div class="block-images-list"><img src="'.$img_path.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" alt="img"></div>
                                <p class="style-title-list">
                                    <a href="#">'.$row["title"].'</a>
                                </p>
                                <ul class="reviews-and-counts-list">
                                    <li><img src="/images/eye-icon.png" alt="eye"><p>0</p></li>
                                    <li><img src="/images/comment-icon.png" alt="comment"><p>0</p></li>
                                </ul>
                                <p class="style-title-list">
                                    <a href="#">'.$row["title"].'</a>
                                </p>
                                <a href="#" class="add-cart-style-list"></a>
                                <p class="style-price-list">
                                    <strong>'.$row["price"].'</strong> грн
                                </p>
                                <div class="style-text-list">
                                    '.$row["mini_description"].'
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        ');
                    } while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
                  }
                } else {
                    echo "<h3>Категория не создана или недоступна!</h3>";
                }
             ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

не выводит текст как h3,а выводит обычный не форматированный текст. Сам файл, где весь код находится, имеет расширение .php и в нём и без того достаточно html-разметки, которая отображается браузером корректно, а именно этот случай, почему-то, игнорирует. Прошу помощи у знатоков :)

Comment: @splash58 как бы вам объяснить) могу приложить всё содержимое моего аццкого быдлокода сюда, если так проще будет понять суть проблемы

Comment: @splash58 в том то и дело, что есть...

Comment: @splash58 присвоил этому h3 id="vasya", прописал стиль в css, и при загрузке получаю это: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'vasya' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\OpenServer\domains\autopartshop.ua\view_cat.php on line 164

Comment: @splash58 прописал, и с экранированными кавычками, и без айдишника просто для h3(а он единственный на странице) - не работает, тот же не форматированный текст...

Comment: @splash58 всё равно та же история)
да, время позднее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931351/how-to-echo-in-php-html-tags

Заметь, что у тебя предшествующий html выводится в одинарных кавычках ' ', попробуй одинарные, как в ссылке выше.

И здесь более красивый вывод html, не нужно использовать echo, просто закрывай ?> и выводи то, что тебе нужно.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100354/how-can-i-echo-html-in-php